# Error while starting hadoop cluster (namenode not working but datanode working)

Tags: linux, hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mapreduce

[image: log for namenode]

Till few hours back everything was working fine but then suddenly namenode stopped working. when i do ./start-all.sh and then jps on namenode then nothing is shown in result. No namenode,datanode. But when i do jps on datanode then it shows proper result of nodemanager and datanode and stuff. Please see the log file. I am not able to understand the error.

Comment: Try ./stop-all.sh and then ./start-all.sh

Comment: did all those things. Formatted the node also. cleared the tmp files also.